# jQuery show decimals based on addition of two intengers

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to build a tip calculator that takes your bill amount and automatically calculates the tip and the total. The problem is with decimal places. I have read around about the toFixed method, but I cannot seem to get it to work. It is close, but I cannot figure out how to restrict and add the decimals I need. Thanks!

```js
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){
 var tenpercent = (10 /100);
$("#checkBill").keyup(function () {
    $('#tenPercent').val($('#checkBill').val() * tenpercent);
 $('#tenTotal').val(parseInt($('#tenPercent').val()) + parseInt($("#checkBill").val()));
});
});
```

```html
<section id="calculatorContainer">

 <div id="billBox">
     <input type"text" id="checkBill">
    </div>
    
    <div id="valueBoxes">
     <ul>
         <li><input type="text" id="tenPercent"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul>
         <li><input type="text" id="tenTotal"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
            <li><input type="text"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

`

```
<div id="billBox">
    <input type"text" id="checkBill">
</div>

<div id="valueBoxes">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" id="tenPercent"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><input tyle="text" id="tenTotal"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
        <li><input tyle="text"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // just ten-percent, or 0.1: don't recalculate a constant every time:
    var tenpercent = 0.1;
    $("#checkBill").keyup(function () {
        // use parseFloat() to retrieve the number from the (string) value,
        // note the calculation wrapped in parentheses, and the call to 'toFixed(2)'
        // chained to the closing parenthesis, meaning toFixed is called on the result
        // of the calculation, not on the operands:
        $('#tenPercent').val((parseFloat($('#checkBill').val()) * tenpercent).toFixed(2));
        // similarly, use parseFloat to get the (probable) floats for addition:
        $('#tenTotal').val((parseFloat($('#tenPercent').val()) + parseFloat($("#checkBill").val())).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bfyp8fow/3).

Or, slightly improved, avoid some of the addition in the latter part, and just multiply the total by `1.1` to have the original (100%) and the tip (10%) added together automatically:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tenpercent = 0.1;
    $("#checkBill").keyup(function () {
        $('#tenPercent').val((parseFloat($('#checkBill').val()) * tenpercent).toFixed(2));
        $('#tenTotal').val(parseFloat(($('#checkBill').val()) * 1.1).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bfyp8fow/2/).

Comment: I will try this out, I am new to doing more development type deals as I use jQuery mostly for design. But I had this idea and wanted to push myself and those decimals were giving me an issue as I knew if I figured just one out 100% I could just use it on the other values.

I will give this ago, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hope it's of help! Note that I updated the jQuery shortly after your comment (I'd somehow forgotten to use `toFixed()` to solve the decimal problem, concerning myself first with the needless calculations; yes, I am embarrassed...).

Comment: Hey David,

  I was trying to add the toFixed myself and kept getting an error. Being new it is hard to know when to place it. It was not updated when I viewed, but it was a TON of help. Def getting credit for this good sir!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help. :)